# PySpark withcolumn not keeping new column

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to save change a column from string to integer, I am getting a nonetype error as shown, I am not sure what is going wrong here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the cell #113, you ended with `printSchema()`, which has return type None. Remove that and your `data_use` will be a dataframe